# 2003 honda accord not starting, starter and battery ok

Tags: honda, ignition, accord

When I turn the key the engine would not start. I wired power to the starter via a cable from the battery and it worked so the starter is ok. When I turn the key no power is going to the starter solenoid, any advice would be appreciated.
p.s. we already checked starter relay fuse.

Comment: Can you hear any clicking in the fuse box when you try to start it?

Comment: What's the engine size? Transmission? Standard or automatic? edit: Actually it seems it doesn't really matter outside of the standard/automatic part.

Comment: The quickest thing to try first is to see if it starts in neutral and make sure it's shifted firmly into park (on an automatic transmission).

Answer (score 1):

If you pull the starter relay located behind the left kick panel #18.

[image]

[image]

Pin 30 and 85 are ignition voltage when the key is in the start position.

Pin 86 is ground from either the transmission range switch or clutch interlock switch. Depending on standard or automatic transmission.

Pin 87 runs to the starter solenoid S terminal.

---

If pins 30 and 85 don't have ignition voltage in the start position. Gain access to the ignition switch connector and backprobe for power on the pin 3 (white) and pin 1 (black/white).

If you have power at pin 3 but not pin 1, you need a new ignition switch. If don't have power at either pin go into the under hood fuse box and check fuses 23 (50A) and fuse 22 (100A). If the fuses are OK you need to do a continuity test from the underhood fuse box to the ignition switch.

---

If you don't have ground on pin 86, (Automatic) gain access to the transmission range switch and check pin 4 (light green or blue) for ground. If you don't have ground on pin 4, check pin 10 (red/white) for ground. If you don't have ground on pin 10 check ground splice G101 for fit. On the 2.4 it's located under the plastic trim on top of the engine. On the 3.0 It's located around the throttle body.

While testing on an automatic try shifting through the drive positions to see if it's not registering that the car is in park.

If you still don't see ground at pin 4 replace the range switch.

On the standard transmission check the clutch interlock switch located on the clutch pedal. It'll be a two wire switch.

---

If everything else checks OK try applying power to pin 87. Does it crank? If so the wiring to the starter is OK and you can replace the relay. If it doesn't crank you need to do a continuity test from the start solenoid S terminal to pin 87 of the relay.

Answer (score 0):

Likely ignition switch.  Check relays and wiring also.

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue with my 03 accord. Changed ignition switch. Bought one on Amazon for something like 50 bucks, youtubed a video how to change (30 minutes) and it worked! No more no starts / no more buzzing sound.